# iOS Core Bluetooth, determine if a peripheral was forgotten by the user?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am working on an app that connects over BLE to a device which has encrypted characterstics.  The app works fine.  What we are trying to determine is if we can detect if the user has gone into the settings app and forgotten the device.  The LTK is removed so we can no longer talk to the device correctly.

When the app starts, it calls CBCentralManager.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:) but that still returns the device.  It seems like that call should return nothing since the user forgot the device but that is not the case.

Does anyone know if this is something that can be determined from the information in the central manager, the peripheral or any of the callbacks.  I am thinking iOS hides this from the apps but figured I'd ask.